# Ubuntu 20.04 does not boot after kernel/grub update

Tags: grub2, kernel, 20.04

```
uname -a
Linux n552vw 5.4.0-45-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 26 13:38:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

After the last kernet ang grub update a few days ago, every time the laptop is started there is an ASUS logo and nothing happens. Pressing Power button and turning the laptop off and then turning on show Grub.

Selecting "Ubuntu" loads the system normally.

Any clues how to diagnose this? Any possible suggestions how to make the system load normal as before?

---

### BIOS version

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
N552VW.304
```

The laptop uses the [latest available BIOS](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/VivoBook-Pro-N552VW/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

### Laptop model

[ASUS N552VW](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/VivoBook-Pro-N552VW/specifications/)

---

### Note

This problem is sporadic (random). The system can load without any problems for days, then sometimes it would stuck (like described above)

#### Boot

```
efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,d504847c-ea29-43e6-9b9a-19965527a48c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,d504847c-ea29-43e6-9b9a-19965527a48c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)..BO
```

### Secure & Fast boot

Are disabled. Have disabled them since the clear install of Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

[image]

### Battery

I am using a power cord 100% of the time. The battery has degraded and does hold the charge well. I ignore this fact, since I never used it.

Wonder if that can cause troubles. Since the problem with the load occurres after the laptop has been off for 1+ day:

```
upower -e | sed -n '2p' | xargs upower -i
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 07 Sep 2020 10:04:56 AM EEST (100 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              26.355 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         33.63 Wh
    energy-full-design:  48 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             15 V
    percentage:          78%
    capacity:            70.0625%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: Try entering bios and disable any fast boot or quiet boot.  This should give more information when booting.